# Git pull with no changes from specified branch?

Tags: git

I'm now on `develop` branch on my project. And I want to pull and merge from branch `origin/Jim`.

There'are some changes between these two branch like below:

```
git diff develop origin/Jim --stat

VERSION                                            |   2 +-
api/account/models.py                              |  32 +--
api/account/views.py                               | 175 ++++--------
```

But when I run command

```
git pull origin Jim
```

It always show me

```
 * branch              Jim        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

What's wrong with my trial.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing unusual about what you have posted.  This:

> ```
> git diff develop origin/Jim --stat
>
> VERSION                                            |   2 +-
> api/account/models.py                              |  32 +--
> api/account/views.py                               | 175 ++++--------
> ```

shows some differences in the commit named by `developer` (hash ID `a123456`, perhaps: use `git rev-parse developer` to see the exact hash ID), vs the commit named by `origin/Jim` (a different hash ID—use `git rev-parse` again if desired—but let's just say it might be commit `9876543`).

This:

> ```
> git pull origin Jim
> ```

"means", to Git, that Git should run the following two commands:

```
git fetch origin Jim
git merge -m ... FETCH_HEAD
```

(I've omitted the actual `-m` argument here, and a few other minor items).  The `git fetch` step causes your Git to reach out to some other Git software: your Git calls up the URL stored under `remote.origin.url`, and some other Git version answers that Internet "phone call" and connects to another (different) repository and collects from that repository any commits they have, that you don't, that you might need in order to update your `origin/Jim`.

This output:

> ```
>  * branch              Jim        -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

implies (depending on your own Git version) that there were no new commits they had that you didn't, so your `origin/Jim` was already up to date with their `Jim`.  No problem so far: this just means there was nothing to fetch.

The *second* command, `git merge FETCH_HEAD`, is then equivalent to `git merge origin/Jim`.  This finds a commit hash ID—`9876543` again, in our example here—and tries merging your current (`HEAD`) commit with that commit.

We don't know what commit is your *current* commit.  We don't know which branch, if any, you're on.  But even if you are on `develop`, so that your current commit is `a123456`, this can *still* produce:

> ```
> Already up to date.
> ```

It will do so if your commit—`a123456`—is strictly "ahead of" commit `9876543` as found under the name `FETCH_HEAD`.

What we know for sure at this point is that you are, at your current commit, *even with* or *strictly ahead of* the `FETCH_HEAD` commit.  The merge command does not mean *overwrite everything, throwing away my changes*.  You have changes that *add on* to their work; your `git merge` is keeping your changes.  They have no *new* work to add on to *your* work, so there is nothing else to do.

Comment: How can I clean my mis-operation? What I can think of is to delete the `develop` branch and do a re-merge work from `Jim`

Comment: It's not at all clear that there is anything wrong. Your branch already contains the work from their `Jim` branch (which you find via your `origin/Jim` remote-tracking name). If you have your own work atop their work, there's no reason the files should match.

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit and push your branch to the server?

maybe it is not synced with the Git server. try to commit your branch and push it to the server.

Comment: Both these two branch were pushed to remote server

Comment: This type of responses are for comments. Try not to post uncertain and low quality answers.